# Does the property file reader works in jmeter non gui mode

Tags: testing, properties, jmeter

I have a jmeter test plan where i am using a property file reader to read properties from a config.properties file and use them in jmeter scripts it is working in gui mode when i run the jmx file in non gui mode then the property file reader is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use 3rd-party elements as you can read data from a custom *.properties* file providing the file name/location via [`-q` command-line argument](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options) like:

- GUI:

  ```
  jmeter -q /path/to/your/properties -t /path/to/testplan.jmx
  ```
- non-GUI:

  ```
  jmeter -q /path/to/your/properties -n -t /path/to/testplan.jmx -t /path/to/results.jtl
  ```

More information:

- [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Overriding Properties Via The Command Line](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)

Answer (score 0):

The component works the same in gui and non gui mode.

Just check that path to file is correct when using Non Gui mode.

Jmeter.log will help you find the issue